# Coverage reports for lib folder in CakePHP using Jenkins?

Tags: cakephp, jenkins, continuous-integration, code-coverage

I am experimenting with using Jenkins with CakePHP as part of my push towards better CI.

I am using the following command for a build job step.

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ABC-MASTER/src/abc/Console/cake testsuite -app 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ABC-MASTER/src/abc app AllTests --log-junit 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ABC-MASTER/build/logs/junit.xml --coverage-clover 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ABC-MASTER/build/logs/clover.xml --coverage-html 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ABC-MASTER/build/coverage
```

This generates coverage reports even for lib folder.

My questions are:

1. Should I generate the coverage html pages for lib folder as well?
2. If not, how do I turn it off?

My code is structured as:

```
build
src
   abc (this is the app folder)
   lib ( this is the Cake lib folder)
tests
   Test (this follows the Cake convention)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has 3 parts:

1) create a phpunit.xml.dist inside the project root.

build
src
   abc (this is the app folder)
   lib ( this is the Cake lib folder)
tests
   Test (this follows the Cake convention)
build.xml
phpunit.xml.dist

2) create the following content inside the phpunit.xml.dist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit>

  <filter>
    <blacklist>
      <directory suffix=".php">src/lib</directory>
    </blacklist> 
  </filter>

</phpunit>
```

3) add in `--configuration /path/to/phpunit.xml.dist` to the command.

In the example given in the question, this becomes:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ABC-MASTER/src/abc/Console/cake test \
--app /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ABC-MASTER/src/abc app AllTests \
--log-junit /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ABC-MASTER/build/logs/junit.xml \
--coverage-clover /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ABC-MASTER/build/logs/clover.xml \
--coverage-html /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ABC-MASTER/build/coverage \
--configuration /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ABC-MASTER/phpunit.xml.dist
```

For more information on how to use phpunit configuration file, look at this [link](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.blacklist-whitelist). It will help to understand how to use the phpunit configuration file in particular the blacklist and whitelist section.